# Отображать items в листе

Tags: android, recyclerview, listview

не могу понять что мне использоваться чтобы так отображать items- в таком дизайне. С диалога я передаю массив значений который выбрал пользователь - тут должен отобразить. В какую обертку мне добавлять массив. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не очень понятна суть вопроса, однако можно сделать вполне обоснованное предположение что вам может подойти либо Chips либо FlexBoxLayout.

Comment: Что мене использовать (обертку) для текста что бы получить аналогичное отображение учитывая что есть массив фраз

Comment: Спасибо, я понял что искать